# Roots property of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

> Let $P = x^d + \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}a_k\,x^k$ a polynomial of a degree $d\geq2$ with real coefficients. Prove that all real or complex roots $\lambda$ of $P$ verify $|\lambda|\leq\left(1,\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}|a_k|\right)$.

I tried to prove that if $|\lambda|>\left(1,\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}|a_k|\right)$ then $\lambda$ is not a root of $P$, but it always leads me to nowhere.

Comment: $|\lambda|^d = |\sum_{k=0}^{d-1} a_k \lambda^j| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} |\lambda|^j\cdot |a_k|$ and divide both sides by $|\lambda|^{d-1}$ when $|\lambda | \geq 1$ to obtain $|\lambda| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} |a_k|$

Comment: This inequality is very useful, I used it to show continuity of coefficients of a polynomial in terms of their roots

Comment: Oh that does answer the question. Big thanks!